# c binary file reading problems

Tags: c, binary, binaryfiles

hi i am reading a binary file using c as shown here [link text](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/c-howto-read-binary-file-into-buffer-172985/)

so that all the information read from binary file is stored in "char *buffer".
i have the format standard where it says that one of the lines should be

```
   format: unsigned char, size: 1 byte
```

i am doing the following:

```
   printf("%x\n", buffer[N]);
```

but what should i do when the format says:

```
   format: unsigned short, size: 2 bytes
```

if i do it as follows, would this be correct:

```
   printf("%d%d\n", buffer[N], buffer[N+1]);
```

if not can you show me the correct way?

Also can you tell me if the following are correct way while printing:

```
   char              %c
   unsigned long     %ul
   unsigned short    %d
   unsigned char     %x
   double            %f
   long              %ld
```

all of the data in binary file is in little-endian format! thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: How are you reading anything using printf?

Comment: i have given a link on how the binary file is read into buffer... i hope i correctly understand you.

Comment: Your link shows how somebody else did it. What does *your* code look like?

Comment: exactly the same as the one answered by the member named The_Nerd

Comment: @sbi: sorry... thanks for removing that tag!

Answer (score 2):

Try `printf("%d", (short)(buffer[N] + buffer[N+1]<<8))`. Now notice that I had to assume that the byte order in the buffer had the least significant byte of the two-byte `short` stored at the lower address.

I could likely have written `*(short *)(&buffer[N])`, but that assumes that N has the right alignment to hold a `short` on your platform, and that the buffer and the platform agree on byte order.

This is actually just the tip of a very large iceberg of a topic. There are many subtle issues lurking, and some really unsubtle ones when you wander into floating point values.

Comment: thanks! can you tell if these are correct: char - %c,
unsigned long - %ul, unsigned short - %d, unsigned char - %x,    double - %f, long - %ld.

Comment: @sdfg, you've got a mix of right and wrong there. Start with the man page for printf(3), and then read about serialization. Google is likely your friend.